# Java - FutureTask not working?

Tags: java

I am creating a Java application. On start up, my application will download all required files. My application will parse XML file and download files from the URL from XML files. I want my application download files "step by step" so i use `FutureTask` My problem is, `FutureTask` is not working for my application.

Here is some part of my code.

Startup.class

```
public void startDownloading()
{

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            downloader.startDownload();
        }
    });
    t.run();
    }
}
```

Downloader.class

```
private LibrariesDownloader ld;
private RDownloader rd;

public Downloader()
{
    this.ld = new LibrariesDownloader(launcher);
    this.rd = new RDownloader(launcher);
}

public void startDownload()
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    FutureTask<Void> libDownloader = new FutureTask<Void>(ld);
    FutureTask<Void> resDownloader = new FutureTask<Void>(rd);
    executor.execute(libDownloader);
    if(libDownloader.isDone())
    {
        executor.execute(resDownloader);
    }
}
```

LibrariesDownloader.class(& RDownloader.class(Code almost the same, only URL is different))

```
public class LibrariesDownloader implements Callable<Void>
{
    private Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY;

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            URL resourceUrl = new URL("http://www.exmaple.com/libraries.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = db.parse(resourceUrl.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream());

            NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Content");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = nodeLst.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == 1)
                {
                    Element element = (Element)node;
                    String key = element.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    final File path = new File("C://test/", key);
                    final String url = "http://www.exmaple.com/dl/" + key;
                    final String fileName = key;
                    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                URL fileURL = new URL(url);
                                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(fileURL, path);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {

                                URL redownloadURL = new URL("http://www.example.com/dl/" + fileName);
                                File p = new File("C://test/", fileName);
                                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(redownloadURL, p);
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void done()
                        {
                            System.out.println(fileName + " had downloaded successfully");
                        }
                    };
                    worker.execute();


                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                launcher.println("An error was found when trying to download libraries file " + e);
            }
            return null;
        }

}
```

There is ton of `<Key></Key>` in my XML file. My application can execute `LibrariesDownloader` and download all libraries files. After all libraries files had downloaded, my application just stop there. It will not execute `RDownloader`.

Is that any code wrong in my application? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Define "not working". Also, you should read the javadoc of Thread.run(), Thread.start() and FutureTask.isDone(). It's very unclear, just from the code, what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want after LibrariesDownloader.class download files, RDownloader will start and download "R" files

Comment: So you want sequential execution instead of parallel execution. Why use threads then? As I said, read the javadoc of isDone(). It's not a blocking method. get() is a blocking method.

Comment: I read all the javadoc of FutureTask before. My code is not working.. Can you help me plz

Comment: So, where did you read that isDone() will wait until the task is complete before returning true or false? Why don't you re-read the javadoc of the get() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a new thread with

> t.run();

It should be `t.start()`. The thread scheduler calls the `run()`.

You probably want a busy/wait loop  or a timeout for `LibrariesDownloader`

```
if(libDownloader.isDone())
    {
        executor.execute(resDownloader);
    }
```

should be

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(libDownloader);

while (!future.isDone()) {
    //bad spin wait
} 

executor.execute(resDownloader);
```

Better still, make a single ThreadPoolExecutor with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` or the more robust `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` and submit both of them. The 2nd task will be queued.

The code snippet would look like

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(libDownloader);
executor.execute(resDownloader);
```

Comment: nonono, i want after `LibrariesDownloader` done downloading, `RDownloader` will start and download another list of files again

Comment: @user2718549 That's what is going to happen. Unless `LibrariesDownloader` finishes, `RDownloader` won't start. Did you try the code ?

Comment: I tried all the codes, both of them is not working, it will start `LibrariesDownloader` and `RDownloader` at the same time...

Comment: @user2718549 You should do `worker.get();` after `worker.execute()` where you are using `SwingWorker`

Comment: where should I put `worker.get()`? I use `SwingWorker` in when `LibrariesDownloader` and `RDownloader` download files because my GUI will "freeze" so i have to run the download process in background

Comment: still can't work.. Both download process started at the same time

Comment: Your code work fine, i replaced `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` to `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`